# A simple matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, printf

I can't figure out why the following code produces `43213987`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        for(int j=3; j>=0; j--)
            if(i%2==0)
                printf("%d", a[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

How the second `3` printed on screen is accessed? How `a[2][3]` can be legal?

Comment: C have no bounds checking. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* which makes the program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: No bounds - Like @Someprogrammerdude said. You are printing your the first and the third row (skipping the second where i=1, 1%2 != 0) and for the colums you loop through 4 steps always beginning at the invalid mark of a[i][3] which produces a random/illegal value. not sure what you are trying to achieve though

Comment: You're printing whatever is in memory address of `arr[2][3]`, which is your array bounds + `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: I had a test today. There was one answer with eight digits. So I assumed the others were incorrect; but how can a particular case be correct if the behavior is undefined and the accessed value is random? Should I point this out to someone?

Comment: It is defined in a sense: you access a particular part of a memory (past your array boundaries). Undefined is what value you get back. I.e. it can be anything what happens to be stored there at the moment (and not necessarily by your own code).

Answer (score 1):

> How a[2][3] can be legal?

No, it is not legal. It is **undefined behavior** because out of array bound.

**c99** draft standard section `Annex J.2 J.2` Undefined behavior includes the follow point:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>   accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>   a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).